# Pivotal category: Why that name?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, higher-category-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory

**Question**
Why are *[pivotal categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pivotal+category)* called pivotal?

**What I can think of:**

- In a (right) rigid monoidal category $\mathbf C$ one draws a morphism $\varphi \in Hom_{\mathbf C}(X, Y)$  in string diagrams as follows:

[image]

Duality is represented by "switching arrows around", i.e.
a morphism $\phi \in Hom_{\mathbf C}(V^*, W^*)$ is drawn as follows:

[image]

Given a morphism $\varphi \in Hom_{\mathbf C}(X, Y)$ the (strict) pivotal structure lets one "pivot" its representing string diagram (turn its arrows around):
[image]

Here we make use of the identification $X^{**}=X$. (The expression $X^*$ is not ambigous because a right rigid pivotal category is left rigid, and left and right dual objects of a given object coincide.)

Comment: I remember spherical categories being named so because you can move morphism around as if they were on a sphere. Now, 'to pivot' more or less means 'to rotate' so perhaps the origin lies in this direction?

Comment: Right, that motivation for the term "spherical" is often given. Even Barrett and Westbury explained the term in their original paper that way, I think. In this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.12532.pdf another (?) motivation is given. The string net space associated to $S^2$ and a pivotal fusion category has dimension 1 if the category is spherical, and 0 otherwise.